# ng-repeat and filter on value - (key, value) in details

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to filter my object inside expression value?

I have this ng-repeat

```
ng-repeat="(series, detailData) in projectDetails"
```

the return of detailData is object which is i need to filter to get exactly field that i need.

```
{"projectViewType":"card1",
 "projectName":"Hamilton",
 "projectType":"Onprocess"},
{"projectViewType":"card2",
 "projectName":"Christone",
 "projectType":"Done"},
{"projectViewType":"card2",
 "projectName":"Villas",
 "projectType":"Done"} .... more
```

I need to filter this result with projectType = Done 
and return all object with projectType = Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projectDetails| filter: { projectType : 'Done' }">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add a standard filter?

```
ng-repeat="(series, detailData) in projectDetails | filter:{'projectType':'Done'}"
```

I don't even think you'd need a custom filter.

Check the docs here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter especially the part where it describes the `expression` argument.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat="(series, detailData) in projectDetails | filter: projectType == "Done" "`